# Указание ссылки на несколько объектов

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код который должен при столкновении отправить одно и то же значение в другие скрипты. Но он выдает ошибку.
Вот собственно сам код:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D collision)
{

    if (collision.gameObject.name == "plat1")
    {
        delete1 plat1 = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<delete1>();
        plat1.Hit(plusone);
        delete2 plat2 = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<delete2>();
        plat2.Hit(plusone);
        delete3 plat3 = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<delete3>();
        plat3.Hit(plusone);

    }
```

Вот код ошибки:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object delplusone.OnCollisionEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collision2D
>   collision) (at Assets/scripts/ScriptsPlus/delplusone.cs:17)

В чем может быть дело? Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: На какой строке ошибка то хоть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое вероятное вот в этой конструкции дело
`delete1 plat1 = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<delete1>();`. Вы здесь пытаетесь получить компонент а в следующей строке его используете. Только перед использованием не проверяете что объект найден, поэтому может ругаться что пустая ссылка. 
Второй вариант `plat1.Hit(plusone);` если у вас компонент и нашелся, то не факт что сам объект `plusone` у вас не пустой в этот момент и при обработке где-то что-то не ломается.